# Does ".class" work for instances of a class in java

Tags: java

I have tried to execute the given code given below:

```
public class XXX
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{System.out.println(new XXX().class);
}
}
```

But the code shows an error during compilation:

```
/XXX.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
{System.out.println(new XXX().class);
                              ^
/XXX.java:4: error: ';' expected
{System.out.println(new XXX().class);
                                   ^
2 errors
```

But when I compile the following code:

```
public class XXX
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{System.out.println(XXX.class);
}
}
```

it works fine,I mean it prints the output as given below

```
class XXX
```

Does this mean that the ".class" operation( I don't know what to call it) in java is only meant for a class and not its instances ?

Comment: But if ".class" provides static access then it should also work for cases of non-static content as

Answer (score 2):

For instances you have to use the method `getClass()`

```
public class XXX
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {System.out.println(new XXX().getClass());
   }
}
```

Comment: but does that mean that ".class" is statically accessed, if so then why can't they be accessed by instances of the class....consider the code below :                 
   class enthrian{